# Docker compose: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I just updated docker desktop for windows and when I run `docker compose up --build app` to refresh a remote image after changes to files, I get the following error. Every other compose command seems to be in order.
Docker compose version: `v2.12.2`

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x187d8c6]

goroutine 12 [running]:
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).getDrivers(0xc000399f80, {0x20a2448, 0xc0005d8db0})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/build_buildkit.go:95 +0xc6
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).doBuildBuildkit(0xc000399f80, {0x20a2448, 0xc0005d8db0}, 0x0?, {0x1d918cd, 0x4})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/build_buildkit.go:47 +0x87
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).doBuild(0xc000399f80, {0x20a2448, 0xc0005d8db0}, 0xc0005a55e0?, 0xc0004b1ad0, {0x1d918cd, 0x4})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/build.go:228 +0xc5
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).ensureImagesExists(0x0?, {0x20a2448, 0xc0005d8db0}, 0xc0005a55e0, 0x0)
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/build.go:134 +0x14d
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).create(0xc000399f80?, {0x20a2448, 0xc0005d8db0}, 0xc0005a55e0, {{0xc000178a80, 0x1, 0x2}, 0x0, 0x0, {0x1d97342, ...}, ...})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/create.go:67 +0x173
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).Up.func1({0x20a2448, 0xc0005d8db0})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/up.go:36 +0xaa
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/progress.Run.func1({0x20a2448?, 0xc0005d8db0?})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/progress/writer.go:61 +0x27
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/progress.RunWithStatus.func2()
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/progress/writer.go:82 +0x87
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
        golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20220819030929-7fc1605a5dde/errgroup/errgroup.go:75 +0x64
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
        golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20220819030929-7fc1605a5dde/errgroup/errgroup.go:72 +0xa5
```

Comment: This sounds like a Docker bug more than something the SO community could help resolve.  But just in case, the backtrace on its own isn't enough to help; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. I had a container that hadn't been updated in 3 months. Then I updated Docker last week, and the container still ran fine. I just re-built the container, and now it's broken with the error above.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem while running docker-compose command.

Solution is very simple in the mac os.
You should use "**sudo**" command before docker-componse.

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways to fix the issue

1. using the command docker compose down (or docker-compose down)
2. uninstall and install docker

and also there is another way

- stop docker by using "sudo service docker stop"
- and try to remove docker from lib "sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker"
- start docker again "sudo service docker start"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).